# React table - filtering through listData to see changes when a dropdown option is selected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select, react-table

I want to filter through listData that populates a react table. When an option is selected in a react select dropdown menu I want the table to only show the rows that have the changes in.

This is what I am trying to do:

````
```  data={_.filter(listData, (row) => {
    return includes(row, row.has_changed);
    })} ```
````

Currently when an option from the dropdown is selected it doesn't do anything.

I am not quite sure how to go about doing this? Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more code/ what code would help.

Comment: Supposing you have array of object, and you want to find the rows which contain "xyz" string in a row, you can do that by 
`array.filter(i => i.column1.includes("xyz") || i.column2.includes("xyz") )` 
The above code would return new array which would satisfy atleast one of the two conditions

Comment: So this is my dropdown:   const filterOptions = [
    { value: '', label: 'Select a column' },
    { value: 'first_name', label: 'First Name' },
    { value: 'last_name', label: 'Last Name' },
    { value: 'email', label: 'Email' },
    { value: 'title', label: 'Title' },
    { value: 'company', label: 'Company' },

Comment: I hope you are storing the "value" that was selected by the user. You can just replace the "xyz" with the state that you are storing in.

Comment: yes so this is my state:   const [valueState, setValueState] = useState('');
This is how I handle the ohChange:   const handleSelectChange = (value) => {
    setValueState(value);
    console.log(value);
  };